# variable was undeclared or was never assigned? and data reader not working?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, debugging, crash

I didn't want to post this but I couldn't find an answer to solve this problem.

Im making an application for a friend, but when I run it, it gives me a warning, and recently started crashing.

I tried debugging the problem, and it gave me a completely different problem.

```
class DBApplication : DBInfo
{
    private MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection();
    private int customer_id;
    public string lastname;

    //constructor
    public DBApplication()
    {
        OrderID();
    }

    public string OrderID()
    {
        customer_id = 8;
        //add the DataBase query to the string.
        string query = "SELECT * FROM wdb_customer WHERE=" + customer_id;

        if (OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            MySqlCommand myComm = connection.CreateCommand();
            MySqlDataReader Reader;
            myComm.CommandText = query;
            /*when I debugged, it said this was the problem? 
              but i dont understand why.*/*
            Reader = myComm.ExecuteReader(); 

            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                lastname = Reader["customer_name"].ToString();
            }
            Reader.Close();
        }
        return lastname;
    }
}
```

the first problem "the variable DB_App is either undeclared or was never assigned."

thats from this script.

```
partial class Form1 {
    ...
    private DBApplication DB_App = new DBApplication();
    ...
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
       this.OrderID.Text = DB_App.lastname;
    }
```

I have also tried DB_App.OrderID(); same problem.

Comment: When you get an exception while debugging, you have the option to view exception details and from there you may get more information in the InnerException, if there is one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is invalid since you miss a column name in `WHERE` clause

To apply a quick fix change

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM wdb_customer WHERE=" + customer_id;
```

to

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM wdb_customer WHERE customer_id = " + customer_id;
                                                 ^^^ use real column name here
```

*On a side note: do not build SQL query strings directly from user input; use parameters instead. It prevents your code from SQL injections*. Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html#connector-net-tutorials-parameters)

This being said your code might look like this

```
...
myComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM wdb_customer WHERE customer_id = @customer_id";
myComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_id", customer_id);
Reader = myComm.ExecuteReader(); 
...
```

Comment: wow its always a MySQL syntax i get wrong Lol.

thank you so much, that solved both my problems.

Comment: @AlexMoreno You're welcome. See updated answer and consider to refactor your code to use parameters.